# Can women in modern dress dine kosher in Kiryat Joel?

Tags: tznius-modesty, satmar

The closest kosher dining to my location is in Kiryat Joel.

Given the nature of that community, I am not sure if it will be comfortable for me and my friends to go to a restaurant there.

Will a woman in pants be unwelcome?
If a man is in shorts and sandals and a kippa, would that be a problem?

Please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: It will likely be hard to answer this question without a working definition of "modern dress".

Comment: @Alex op enhanced

Comment: I suppose it's quite an opinion-based question, as we don't know each and everyone in Kiryas Yoel. In Israel most charedim ignore non-modestly dressed people by staring at the ground, but they are more used to tourists, which is not the case there. I can only conjecture that they would be more concerned with exposing body parts that shouldn't be exposed.